# Python how to: convert set to int

Tags: python, python-3.2

can some one please explain to me how I could go about converting a set to an int, its homework

when i need to compare the length of the set to the length of a list or something else?

```
lst = []
oldset =set()
word_set = {}


    while True:
    inp = input('Enter text: ')

    if inp == '':
        print('Finished')
        break

    lst = inp.split()
    for word in lst:
        oldset.add(word)
        oldset = len(oldset)# im sure that this line is my error it tells me to remove .add but i need that

    if word_count < len(word_set):
        word_count[word] = len(word_set.keys())
    print(word,word_count)
```

the error message i am receiving is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                         
  File "./input_counter.py", line 17, in <module>                                                                                                                          
    oldset.add(word)                                                                                                                                                       
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Explain the **entire** problem, in English, in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this code:

```
for word in lst:
    oldset.add(word)
    oldset = len(oldset)
```

But what you are actually accomplishing is as follows: you loop through all the words in `lst`, and for each word, you try to add the word to `oldset`, and then you demolish `oldset` and replace it with an `int` -- the length of `oldset`. This obviously only works once, because after you do it once, `oldset` is no longer a `set`, but is now an `int`.

Understand that a `set` is a *container* -- it contains many other things -- while an `int` is simply a value -- it's just a number. What are you trying to do here? Tell us more...

Comment: thanks my goal is to Loop through the list of words and add each one to the set. If the set increases in size (indicating this word has not been processed before), add the word to the dict as a key with the value being the new length of the set. Using another loop, display the list of words in the dict along with their value, which represents the order in which they were discovered by the program. however im working through one part at a time trying to figure it out

Comment: @Mike, ok, a couple of observations. First, if you want to watch the size of the set, store that value in a separate variable. Before your loop, `wordset_size = len(oldset)`; then in the loop, `if len(oldset) != wordset_size: wordset_size = len(oldset)` and so on. But I question your use of a set at all. Your `word_set` variable is actually a _dict_, not a set, and I don't see why you need a set at all. A `set` is just a `dict` that only stores keys. Why not just check if the word is in `word_dict`, and if not, put it in like so: `word_dict[word] = len(word_dict)`.

Answer (score 5):

Where `s` is your set, do `len(s)`. This will return the number of elements in the set.

Please don't refer to this as "converting a set to an int". That's not what you're doing - you're getting the cardinality of the set, and it's not a "conversion" because the int you get isn't some alternate *representation* of the original, it's a number which holds a *property* of the original.

Comment: thanks for the comment i have tried that and i get an error

Comment: @Mike "I get an error" is less than helpful. What error? What code did you try?

Comment: @Mike, edit your question to show us the code that causes the error.

Comment: If you're getting an error you should post it. This is pretty well trodden territory.

Comment: i will be more careful in my naming next time i appologize